# Android and Spreadsheet interaction

Tags: java, android, google-sheets

I am developing an app and I need the app to be able to post data into a spreadsheet. I hear google API has something for this?

Does it handle creating spreadsheets and then adding data to tables etc?

Comment: Side note: Please avoid all sorts of "thank you notes", "searched a lot" and other text not directly related to you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the process is:

```
- Create spreadsheet
- Upload it to the web (google docs spreadsheet) 
- It gives you a URL to the spreadsheet
- Send data to it via JSON requests
```

To learn more about how to implement it see [this article here](https://coderwall.com/p/duapqq) which talks about how to [Use a Google Spreadsheet as your JSON backend](https://coderwall.com/p/duapqq) or for more links type that term in to google.

Also don't see this as an easy way out to not having to deal with a database, if you are designing an app and you need it to be secure then you are better off learning how to use `sqlite` or the likes